# Conditional Probability for a Lottery

Tags: probability

24 prices are given out for a lottery. 4 are cars, 8 are bicycles, and 12 are for watches. Anna, Ben and Cal are 3 of the prize winners, and choose a prize at random.

What is the probability that Ann wins a car given that Ben wins either a car or a bicycle?

So far I have found the correct answer by saying:

P(Ben wins a car) X P(Ann wins car) + P(Ben wins a bicycle) X P(Ann wins car)

= 4/12 * 3/23 + 8/12 * 4/23 = 11/69

The problem I have is that I cannot get the right answer when using:

P(A|B) = P(A intersection B)/ P(B)

Nothing seems to work to get 11/69

Was,wondering if anyone can help?

Bruce

Comment: Well, $P(B)=\frac 12$, $P(A\cap B)=\frac 4{24} \times \frac {11}{23}$ so...

Comment: Fantastic Lulu, thank you so much. So obvious! Bruce

Answer (score 1):

A-ann,B-ben,C-cal,P-probability function

Required prob. is

> $P(A\text{ winning Car})\times P(B\text{ winning Cycle})\times P(C\text{ winning anything from the rest})+P(A\text{ winning Car})\times P(B\text{ winning Car})\times P(C\text{ winning anything from the rest})$

From the data it is,

> $(1/4)(1/8)(1/22)+(1/4)(1/3)(1/22)=1/192$

Comment: This answer is much too low.  Even if we knew that $B$ had won a car, that would give $A$ a $\frac 3{23}$ at a car.  Not sure why you bring poor $C$ into it at all...

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but Lulu has correct answer. Looks like poor old C ends up with just a cheap watch.

Comment: And Lulu? "You know you make me wanna........." not SHOUT!

Comment: Also, I am confused as to why P(B) is 11/23 and not 12/24 when used in P(A intersection B) why can it not be 12/24 * 3/23. And why are they dependant events. When doing P(C gets car| B and C get cars) the events are independent)